# Output of array not correct

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to push the number of merge request for each project (with id).

My problem is that output of my countertotal is wrong.

```
var counter = 0;
let tab = [695,698,1297,818,923,861] // id of my project
let countertotal = [];
for(var i=0;i<tab.length;i++){
    url = "https://git.int..com/api/v4/projects/"+tab[i]+"/merge_requests?state=opened&private_token=***";
    request(
        {
            url : url
        },
        function (error, response, body) {
            if(error){
                console.log(error);
            }else{        
                getProjects(body)
            }          
        }
        );
    }


    function getProjects(response) {
        var Json = JSON.parse(response);
        for(var i=0; i<Json.length;i++){
            counter++;
        }
        countertotal.push(counter)
        console.log(countertotal)

    }
```

Actual result :

- [0,0,0,0,0,2]

Expected result:

- [0,0,2,0,0,0]

Indeed the id 1297 get 2 merge request but in my array, it is in the last position and not third..

Thanks for your help ;)

Comment: The responses to async requests do not have to arrive in the order you call them. You have to explicitly track that yourself. Or parse the number out of the url again. Or use promises to keep the response callbacks in the same order as the requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea why the **counter** is incremented and **not reset** for different projects, which will end up in addition of previous project counter along with the current project counter.

So if you would like to hold only the counters of a particular project that should not affect the counter value of other projects then here is the code with some of the optimizations.

```
let tab = [695,698,1297,818,923,861],countertotal = [];

// Resolve or Reject Promise based on the response from the api
let promises = tab.map(id=>new Promise((res,rej)=>request(`https://git.int..com/api/v4/projects/${id}/merge_requests?state=opened&private_token=***`,(err,resp,body)=>{
    err ? rej(err) : res(body);
})));
// Actions to be performed on resolve or reject of promises
Promise.all(promises).then(data=>data.map(resp=>getProjects(resp))).catch(err=>{
    console.log(err);
});

function getProjects(response) {
    var Json = JSON.parse(response);
    countertotal.push((Json && Json.length) || 0);
}
```

Or

Change your logic accordingly on **getProjects** function

Comment: @tata titi Please do an upvote if my answer is really helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create a promise array first for all your requests and the use Promise.all to get all the response in sequence.

```
    let tab = [695,698,1297,818,923,861] // id of my project
    let countertotal = [];
    let promiseArr = [];

    for(var i=0;i<tab.length;i++){
        url = "https://git.int..com/api/v4/projects/"+tab[i]+"/merge_requests?state=opened&private_token=***";

       promiseArr.push(new Promise(resolve => {
        request(url, function(err, response, body) {
          resolve(body);
        });
       }));
        }

     Promise.all(promiseArr)
     .then(data => {
       data.forEach(function(res) {
      getProjects(res);
      });
     });


        function getProjects(response) {
            var counter = 0;

            var Json = JSON.parse(response);
            for(var i=0; i<Json.length;i++){
                counter++;
            }
            countertotal.push(counter)
            console.log(countertotal)

        }
```

Comment: Got problem: "await is only valid in async function"

Comment: Unfortunately, get outuput: [0,0,2,2,2,2]

Comment: Check whether the responses are coming in order or not. Output depends on your data.

Comment: Use counter variable locally in your get projects function. You used it as a global variable. Check updated answer.